# .NET Web API - Unexpected type

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Using the new ASP.NET MVC Web API, I'm getting the following error

`The type InfoboardPage was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.`

I'm attempting to return a list of objects which all derive from the same class: `InfoboardItem`

I have added an `XmlInclude` attribute for each of the involved types, as instructed, but I'm still getting this error.

```
[HttpGet]
[XmlInclude(typeof(InfoBoardEvent))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(InfoboardPage))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(InfoboardEventVisitor))]
public List<InfoboardItem> Pages(int ClientNum, int SiteNum, int LangNum)
{
    Data infoboardData = new Data(ClientNum, SiteNum, LangNum, 1);
    var obRetVal = infoboardData.GetPageSequence("~/InfoBoard");

    return obRetVal;
}
```

Has anybody seen this issue before? Is there a solution? Or is this an issue with the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `[XmlInclude]` declaration to the InfoboardItem type, not to the operation, to return the derived elements as XML.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks a lot. Now to solve the new, vague error!